# How do I install lxc 0.9.0 on ubuntu Saucy

Tags: 13.10, lxc

Ubuntu Saucy is shipping with lxc 1.0.0 alpha, it appears to be broken with Docker.

How do I install 0.9.0 on it?

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded at this by pursuing the following course of action:

1/ First, removing lxc 1.0. alpha something

```
$: sudo apt-get purge lxc
```

2/ Cleanup all dependencies

```
$: sudo apt-get autoremove
```

3/ Installing specific version of lxc

```
$: sudo apt-get install lxc=0.9.0-0ubuntu3.6
```

4/ and finishing by installing docker again, following these instructions

http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: no worky, it does not find the version, did you add another source?

Comment: 0.9.0 was not stable with docker either. I ended up with installing 0.8 version of lxc by building the source on my machine